# Example on Local Systems: Flat Connections

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections, holonomy, local-systems

I am reading about the local system, and a local system $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$ with values in $\mathcal{C}$ is defined as a functor
$$
\mathcal{L}:\Pi(X)\to \mathcal{C}
$$
where $\Pi(X)$ is the fundamental groupoid of $X$.

In the article, it gives an example of a flat connection: Let $X$ be a smooth manifold and $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of real vector spaces. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a vector bundle on $X$ equipped with a flat connection. Then it says it is a local system. For a path $p:I\to X$, $\mathcal{L}_p$ should be a parallel transport along $p$. However, I know that in general, the parallel transport along two curves may differ even though when they are in the same homotopy class. So I assumed that there is something with a flat connection. But I am having trouble proving that, when $X$ is a smooth manifold with a flat connection, two curves in a same homotopy class gives same parallel transports. Can you please give me any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: First verify that every point in $X$ has a neighborhood where parallel transport is independent of the path between two points.

Comment: I didn't really understand the question, but perhaps your definition of 'flat connection' is worth writing. A connection (say on a vector bundle) is often *defined* to be flat if parallel transport depends only on the homotopy class of the path in the base. In this case, the parallel transport is functorial on the fundamental groupoid almost by definition.

Comment: @Arrow I don't remember either what I meant when I was saying 'flat connection,' since it was quite  a long time ago, but I think I used another yet equivalent definition of the flat connection. Maybe I defined a flat connection as a connection with zero curvature.